# Is pypi's vaderSentiment and NLTK's vader sentiment is same?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, vader

https://pypi.org/project/vaderSentiment/

vs

https://www.nltk.org/howto/sentiment.html
(Check for vader in above link)

It seems to be same, Anyone can confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Both seem to be the same. I applied both on the same input and it gives the exact same output.